# Min-height of nested divs

Tags: css

I have a bunch of nested divs, at the middle of which is some content. I want the div with the content to have a minimum height of the outer most div.

Has anyone managed to do this?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGbR/) is an example of what I am trying to do, I have put the code below. I want the min-height of `#c` to be `#a`s height. This *should* render a green box, but its actually red.

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            Content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

​​#a { height: 100px; }
#b { min-height: 100%; background-color: red}
#c { min-height: 100%; background-color: green}
​
```

I am not worried about it working on anything but modern browsers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hLGbR/12/

Comment: Using height doesn't work because when the content is longer than #a I want it to grow

Comment: That was not your question… Take a look at the answer of Simon Pertersen and accept it. Works as you wanted imho.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, your div #a has a fixed height and if his is the case:

Try using this styling on `#a`

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and adding to #b and #c

```
display: inline;
```

This is what your fiddle should look like, just tested and it works:

```
#a { min-height: 100px; overflow:hidden;}
#b { min-height:100%; background-color: red; display:inline;}
#c { min-height:100%; background-color: green; display:inline;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are close:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            Content here<br />
            her is more content<br />
            Content here<br />
            her is more content<br />
            Content here<br />
            her is more content<br />
            Content here<br />
            her is more content<br />
            Content here<br />
            her is more content<br />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a { height: auto; }
#b { min-height:100%; background-color: red}
#c { min-height:100%; background-color: green;}​
```

​**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLGbR/13/)** (reEdit) of @gearsdigital's answer